# BigQuery COALESCE for synonymous structs in wildcard query

Tags: google-bigquery, chrome-ux-report

In the table `chrome-ux-report.all.201910` and earlier we had a field named `experimental.first_input_delay`. As of `chrome-ux-report.all.201911` the same data has been renamed to `first_input.delay`.

Prior to this change, I've used wildcard queries like `chrome-ux-report.all.*` to aggregate all YYYYMM data, but now these queries are failing because the field name is different. I'm looking for a fix that can accommodate either old or new field names. Here's a simplified example:

```sql
SELECT
  COALESCE(first_input.delay.histogram.bin, experimental.first_input_delay.histogram.bin) AS fid
FROM
  `chrome-ux-report.all.*`
```

This results in an error that `first_input_delay` doesn't exist in the schema for the `experimental` struct:

> Error: Field name first_input_delay does not exist in STRUCT<time_to_first_byte STRUCT<histogram STRUCT<bin ARRAY<STRUCT<start INT64, end INT64, density FLOAT64>>>>>` at [2:58]

Of course, the field exists in that struct for some of the tables covered by the wildcard but not others. It seems the validator only looks at the most recent table.

So my question is whether it's possible to use something like `COALESCE` to accommodate a field that gets renamed across tables? I understand that the schema makes this harder for us and a better solution is to use a single partitioned table but I'd like to hear if this is solvable given our current setup.

Comment: Standard SQL is assumed. Table queries in legacy SQL might help but that's a dealbreaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try offering your users a view - a starting point could be:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `fh-bigquery.public_dump.chrome_ux_experimental_input_delay_view_202001`
AS
SELECT * EXCEPT(experimental)
  , experimental.first_input_delay.histogram.bin AS fid
  , CONCAT('2018', _table_suffix) ts
FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.2018*` 
UNION ALL
SELECT * EXCEPT(largest_contentful_paint,  experimental), experimental.first_input_delay.histogram.bin
  , CONCAT('20190', _table_suffix) ts
FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.20190*`  
UNION ALL
SELECT * EXCEPT(largest_contentful_paint,  experimental), experimental.first_input_delay.histogram.bin
  , '201910'
FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.201910`   
UNION ALL
SELECT * EXCEPT(largest_contentful_paint,  experimental, first_input, layout_instability), first_input.delay.histogram.bin
  , '201911'
FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.201911`   
UNION ALL
SELECT * EXCEPT(largest_contentful_paint,  experimental, first_input, layout_instability), first_input.delay.histogram.bin
  , '201912'
FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.201912`
```

Now your users can run queries like:

```sql
SELECT ts, origin, fid
FROM `fh-bigquery.public_dump.chrome_ux_experimental_input_delay_view_202001` 
LIMIT 10
```

[image]

Ps: These tables really need to be clustered - this [query would process significantly less bytes](https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/1210266845644767232) if the tables were so.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  #Use coalesce for all the fields existing in the two tables#
  COALESCE(t1.first_input.delay.histogram.bin, t2.experimental.first_input_delay.histogram.bin) AS fid
FROM
(SELECT * FROM  `tables-with-old-field`) t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM  `tables-with-new-field`) t2
ON t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key
```

Just edited the query. Please let me know if it works

Comment: "tables-with-old-field" kind of glosses over the heart of the problem. As I commented in the other answer, using a wildcard isn't possible. IIUC that only leaves manually UNIONing every single table by name.

Comment: I tested this query in some tables I built. It is suposed to work with wildcards

Answer (score 0):

The `*` wildcard character unions tables together, so the `COALESCE` will only have one or the other available to use.  When you call `COALESCE` with both columns as arguments, it will fail.

You will want to process each schema differently and then union them.

```
with old_stuff as (
  -- Process the old data
  select some stuff
  from `chrome-ux-report.all.*`
  where _TABLE_SUFFIX <= '201910'
),
new_stuff as (
  -- Process the new data
  select and rename some stuff
  from `chrome-ux-report.all.*`
  where _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '201911'
),
unioned as (
  select * from old_stuff 
  union all 
  select * from new_stuff
)
select * from unioned
```

Select, Rename, and Cast as needed within each CTE.

Comment: Won't this process the entire dataset twice, doubling the cost? AFAIK the "WHERE" clause doesn't have an effect on the query execution time/cost.

Comment: No.  Your original query was selecting all tables using the wildcard `*` without a filter, mine is doing the same, but split into 2 batches using `_TABLE_SUFFIX` as a filter.  I would read https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables to understand what is going on, especially the 2nd paragraph.  The other solution to this question will also work, but you will have to `COALESCE` all fields that you need.

Comment: This approach won't work because it still uses wildcards. You can't refer to the old field name when using a wildcard because it validates against the newest table schema. This is the same issue I ran into in the original question.

Comment: `UNION` is a good idea, but `chrome-ux-report.all.*` won't work as the schemas need to match (as said in the previous comment) - see my answer for a longer way of specifying the tables